# How to pass multiple types of parameters to be used in a "throw exception" method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a private method where I'm throwing an exception if the value of whatever is passed in for the other methods is null regardless of the type of parameter that is passed in. So say in a constructor you have the following code below:

```
public void add(int num) {
    exceptionCreator(num);
}

public void print(String something) {
    exceptionCreator(something);
}

public void gamePiece(customObject blah) {
    exceptionCreator(blah);
}

private void exceptionCreator([A type that works with all of them] sample) {
    if(sample == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

How would I make it work with different types without creating a bunch of throws of similar argument?

Comment: You might want to look at [Objects.requireNonNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-) instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is not a reference type, and thus cannot be `null`. Your other two (`String` and `customObject` [which should be `CustomObject`]) are reference types and so they can be `null`.

The base type of all reference types is `Object`, so that's what you'd want for your `exceptionCreator`. While it would work to call it with an `int` (because of autoboxing), it would be pointless as it would never throw.

So:

```
public void add(int num) {
    // Possible but pointless; it will never throw
    exceptionCreator(num);
}

public void print(String something) {
    exceptionCreator(something);
}

public void gamePiece(CustomObject blah) {
    exceptionCreator(blah);
}

private void exceptionCreator(Object sample) {
    if (sample == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was it! And yeah hahaha I realized how dumb it was to put int there (just trying to quickly create different type parameters). Thanks!